# Relocating files while extracting RPM

Tags: rpm, cpio

I'm trying to extract files from relocatable RPMs and am facing the current problem:

```
rpm2cpio my.rpm | cpio -ivd
```

works very well but I get the full path of the files, including the default prefix which I would like to change on the fly.

I therefore tried:

```
rpm2cpio my.rpm | pax -r -s '/oldprefix/newprefix/'
```

which does work except for some small rpms, where I get:

> pax: Invalid blocksize 616 bytes.
>   pax: Success. Sync pipe read error on pid 7074 flags 0x200.

I haven't been able to sort this out by using different blocksizes, so I'm now trying to use the --rename-batch-file option of cpio, but it doesn't seem to be documented. As far as I can see I can pass it the output of cpio -t where I've replaced the old prefix by the new one.

Anybody knows if I'm correct in thinking that ?

Comment: For the `pax` you might try interposing a `| dd iflag=fullblock ` in the pipe from rpm to see if it helps. Also `rpm` has a `--root` option to specify a temp dir to chroot to for `-i`. You'll need to sudo and probably add `--nodeps`.

Comment: The dd command unfortunately did not solve the issue.

On the other hand, I found out that cpio has a "--rename-batch-file" option which allows specifying a list of file names instead of doing the rename interactively.

Comment: Good to know it is that simple to use, though my cpio does not have that option, sadly. Still, writing an `expect` script to handle the `-r` interaction wouldnt be too difficult, I suppose.

Comment: Have you tried the option itself. According to the source code, it was added a long time ago but never added to the doc.

Comment: I just tried it and it works! What an amazing discovery, thanks. It isnt even in the `--help` output.

Comment: Your `pax` is based on `star`. `star` implements a FIFO with two processes and shared memory and older versions of star did write this warning when not all bytes from the archive have been processed by the FIFO consumer. With some`cpio` based archives, this is however the default since `cpio` uses a blocksize of 5kB but has no internal blocking and works byte-wise. The warning goes away with a recent `star` version.

Answer (score 0):

another option to extract with "rpm2cpio my.rpm | cpio -ivd" is to use chroot command to save you for getting files somewhere into /.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not root on that host so cannot use chroot...